# How to make the scrolling stop when I take the finger off the UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I want the image to move only when i am moving it. When i swipe and take the finger off, it shouldnt move on its own. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

This is what you are looking for:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate; // called on finger up if user dragged. decelerate is true if it will continue moving afterwards
```

- From Apple's Documentation.

Comment: This is more like it - I didn't look through the delegate protocol

Comment: I can know that when i stopped dragging. But how to make the scrolling also stop at that instant?

Comment: Yes, just have decelerate = NO and its done. 

PS: I had to recreate Photos app fully for a project without using any external frameworks (Three20 etc) which made me master scroll views. :)

Comment: You can call this method in touchesEnded and pass "NO" for willDecelerate parameter. Like this: 

[self scrollViewDidEndDragging:scrollView willDecelerate:NO];

Comment: - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 [self scrollViewDidEndDragging:myScrollView willDecelerate:NO];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
 
}
I did like this but to no effect.

Comment: Ohh... Hmmm... I think you need to also check in the scrollViewDidEndDragging method if(decelerate == NO){ Make it stop by doing something here. } . :)

Comment: Since I have subcalssed UIScrollView for the touch functions to work, now the touch event methods are inside the subclassed file. So where should I call the function u said and what should be its parameters.
Is this correct?     [self scrollViewDidEndDragging:self willDecelerate:NO];

Comment: This seems to be correct though i assume that you are posting here because it didnt work for you. :P.  I will send you the source code i have when i am home. Lets hope i remember that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try and play with decelerationRate.

Comment: I did, but didnt get much success.

Comment: The method i mentioned above should do it for you.